# Creating a function to perform a calculation and add answer as column to existing dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to work out how to create a user defined function to perform a calculation on a series of columns in a dataframe, and add the answer as an additional column to the same dataframe. To keep things simple, the test example I have been using is to calculate percentage growth from one year to the next, but the goal is to be able to create more elaborate calculations that are too cumbersome and repetitive to manually calculate.

The practice data I have been using is...

```
    a <- c(10, 12)
    b <- c(11, 9)
    df <- t(data.frame(a, b))
    df <- data.frame(df)
    colnames(df) <- c(2001, 2002))
```

Which will look like...

```
      2001 2002
    a   10   12
    b   11    9
```

The manual calculation I have been using is...

```
    df$PercGrowth <- (df$`2002` - df$`2001`) / df$`2001` * 100
```

Which returns:

```
      2001 2002 PercGrowth
    a   10   12   20.00000
    b   11    9  -18.18182
```

How do I turn this into a user defined function where I can specify the columns to perform the calculation, and then have the answer added to the dataframe as a derived value?

What I initially thought might work was...

```
    pg <- function(data, c1, c2)
      df <- mutate(data, PercGrowth = ((df[c2] -df[c1]) / df[c1] * 100))

    pg(df, 1, 2)
```

However I keep getting the error message:

Error: Column `PercGrowth` is of unsupported class data.frame

How do I get this to work?

Comment: the names of your columns will be numbers?

Comment: The initial use was based on sales figures from year to year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually more complicated than it looks - you need to use dplyr pronouns and quasiquotation in order to pass the column names as arguments in the function. The following code works:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- c(10, 12)
b <- c(11, 9)
df <- t(data.frame(a, b))
df <- data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- c("year1", "year2")

pg <- function(df, col1, col2) {
  quo_col1 <- enquo(col1)
  quo_col2 <- enquo(col2)
  df %>% 
    mutate(pct_growth = (!! quo_col2 - !! quo_col1) / !! quo_col1 * 100)
}

pg(df, year1, year2)
```

I renamed the columns to strings so they are easier to work with. You can read more at this link: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Another option could be to use some kind of string matching on the column names you're interested in, perform operations using those columns, and then join the result back to the main data frame.